# Can we ask about ideas for software here?

Tags: discussion, scope, policy

I have a friend in university, we both have a project this semester but we're not going to do it together.

The project is basically like a senior product but you come with the idea, anyway the truth is I don't like his idea but he finds it wonderful, I want to convince him to let it but I don't have the facts because the idea goes under criminal justice and I know nothing about it (except from films which are not real world).

Can I ask a question like "is this a good idea to have in real world" or like "is this a good idea for a project" on this site? If not does Stack Exchange have an apropriate site?

Comment: You always have chat though... :)

Comment: As Journeyman already pointed out, this question is "opinion based" and thus off-topic on all stackexchange sites. I would go to the chat room of http://academia.stackexchange.com/ to ask the question.

Answer (score 4):

Nope nope and nope.

Hate to say it but first and foremost, that is *clearly* not a recommendation for a software. There's no real problem definition even, outside "I have no idea what I want to do for my project, but I don't really like the other guy's idea"

"Is this a good idea to have in real world" and such is *opinion based*. It dosen't really solve a real world problem, and you should be asking your professor/TA this.

So no, you *could* try asking such a question, but it would be swiftly shut down as off topic.

Comment: this doesn't answer the second part of the question

Comment: and we're in holiday actually, the semester hasn't practically begun, and the professors don't seem to be on facebook and we don't know their telephones

Comment: @niceman It answers all 3 parts of your question: "ask whether it's a good idea for real world" → Nope. "for a project" → Nope. "Does SE have an appropriate site for that" → Nope. That was the meaning of "Nope, nope and nope". Sorry.